# SML: Exception while reading a line of integers

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

```
fun parse file =
 let
(* A function to read an integer from specified input. *)
     fun readInt input =
   Option.valOf (TextIO.scanStream (Int.scan StringCvt.DEC) input)


 
          in
              (Array.update(acc,readInt inStream, f+1); readInts (i - 1) sumd acc has)
          end
 in
      (a, b, readInts b 0 empty [])
 end
(* ................................................................*)
```

I want to read from a text file that will contain 2 lines:
the first will contain 2 integers a, b
the second will contain b integers x1, x2,.. xb.
for example it will be in this form :

```
    a b 
    n1 n2 n3 .. nb
```

I get this error message :

```
uncaught exception Option
  raised at: Basis/Implementation/option.sml:19.25-19.31
```

Line 19: is basically `readInts i sumd acc has` if that helps.
The problem with my code is because of readInts function. **I want to read integer by integer, and not the whole line at once** (so I can not use functions like `"explode"`)
(it's not like I am forced to do it that way, but it's move time productive to read once and form my desired array acc and list has, instead of reading and storing the b integers in a buffer list and then re-run the list to form my wanted data).
Can you see what's the problem with my code?

Comment: `Option.valOf` will raise `Option` when it's applied to `NONE`. Are you sure the input you give to `readInt` _always_ starts with a valid decimal literal (or whitespace followed by one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `readInt` twice in the second case of `readInts`, advancing the stream past two numbers instead of just one. As you have `b` numbers in your input, but do this `b` times, you attempt to read `2 * b` numbers and eventually can't anymore. When this happens `TextIO.scanStream (Int.scan StringCvt.DEC) input` is `NONE`, so `Option.valOf` raises `Option`.

Comment: I feel embarrassed you are right, thank you

Comment: @brucebanner ... Don't be embarrassed... at some stage or the other, it happens with every one.... On a positive note, you helped me get to know a new thing.. and kudos to you for that..